# Google map geocoder is not returning correct geo location

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm having problems using geocoder and returning correct lat / lang coordinates.

The `controller` address is returning correct geo location, but when I'm using the character `ø` in the address, I'm gettin som weird coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
$controller = "Skovveien+7+0257+oslo+norway";
// base = Strømmen Storsenter, Støperiveien 5, 2010 Strømmen, Norway
$t1 = htmlentities("Str&oslash;mmen+Storsenter+2010+str&oslash;mmen+norway", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$t2 = htmlentities("St&oslash;periveien+5+2010+str&oslash;mmen+norway", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');


$adr = htmlentities($controller, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$res = getGeoLocation($adr);
echo '<p>Controll<br/> Lat: '.$res['lat'].' Lng: '.$res['lng']. '<p/>';

$adr = htmlentities($t1, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$res = getGeoLocation($adr);
echo '<p>Shopping mall<br/> Lat: '.$res['lat'].' Lng: '.$res['lng']. '<p/>';

$adr = htmlentities($t2, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$res = getGeoLocation($adr);
echo '<p>Adresse + post code<br/> Lat: '.$res['lat'].' Lng: '.$res['lng']. '<p/>';



public function getGeoLocation($adr) {  
  // Decode special chars
  $adr = html_entity_decode($adr, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

  $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$adr&sensor=false";

  $jsonData   = file_get_contents($url);
  $geocode    = json_decode($jsonData);

  if($geocode->status == 'OK') {
    $geocode    = $geocode->results[0];
    $res['lat'] = $geocode->geometry->location->lat;
    $res['lng'] = $geocode->geometry->location->lng;
    return $res;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I know it seems a bit pointless first using `htmlentities`, then using `html_entity_decode` in the function. But if I don't, Google returns `ZERO_RESULT`.

Can anyone help me with correct code for fetching lat/lang address for street names with international characters?

Comment: 1. Get rid of all the `htmlentities()` stuff. 2. What character encoding is your PHP file in? If it's UTF-8, it should work - I would try that first

Comment: 1. Done. No vhange. I also removed `html_entity_decode` - Still no change. 2. It's UTF-8. But "in real life" addresses are retrieved from DB and the tables are in `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PHP file is UTF-8 encoded, this condensed example should work:

```
$adr = urlencode("Strømmen Storsenter, Støperiveien 5, 2010 Strømmen, Norway");
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$adr&sensor=false";
$jsonData   = file_get_contents($url);
```

**Edit:** Weirdly, I get an `APPROXIMATE` address when I use

> Strømmen Storsenter, Støperiveien 5, 2010 Strømmen, Norway

but a `ROOFTOP` one when I use only the street address:

> Støperiveien 5, 2010 Strømmen, Norway

Even though, as you can see on the map, Google is perfectly aware that a location named "Strømmen Storsenter" exits at that particular address!

This doesn't look like a character set issue after all, but a weirdness in the way how Google parses requests with place names in it.

Comment: Yes it did. I will have to investigate this further then. Thanks.

Comment: @Steven yeah, no problem. But check out my update in case you didn't see it

Comment: just one "catch". I'm storing all `æ,ø,å` characters like `&oslash;` in the database. I did this because character encoding was a pain in the a***. So `urlencode("Str&oslash;mmen...` does not work. I guess I have to decode reverse the `&oslash;` then.

Comment: @Steven yeah, you'll have to decode those. Or don't HTML encode at all and fix the encoding issues - cumbersome, I know, but that would be the ideal way to go :)

Comment: That will be stage two. Don't fix it, if it aint broken :p

Comment: PS. That's what I 'm testing now - to see if there is a difference in geo position when using shopping mall name in address.